# DAO SQLITE MVP Android

Tags: android

Estou criando um projeto e estou usando 3 camadas.. apresentação, logica e acesso a dados!
Na minha classe de dados eu preciso fazer acesso ao DAO(sqlite) porem preciso do context para utilizar minha DAO, porem não posso usar o context nessa classe por que o context pertence a camada apresentação! como posso resolver esse problema?

Answer (score 1):

Pode usar o contexto geral da aplicaçlão `getAplicationContext()`

Veja se funciona assim.

Answer (score 0):

Tem uma maneira de se criar um contexto vou escrever um exemplo

```
public class DAO extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

   public DAO (Context context){
       super(context,DB_NAME,null,VERSAO);
   }
}
```

Se for na DBController

```
   public class DBController {

        private SQLiteDatabase db;
        private DAO dao;

        public DBController(Context context){
            dao = new DAO(context);
        }
}
```

Foi assim que consegui um contexto. Qualquer duvida estou a disposição.